# ${mdlc:item=RequestId} and ${aspnet-request-posted-body} not returning data

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, nlog

I am using  `${aspnet-request-posted-body}` in my nlog.config file ,I have also added configuartions in startup file. but  `${aspnet-request-posted-body}` not logging request body and `${mdlc:item=RequestId}` also not working

```xml
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\Logs\Api_.log"
                layout="==>[${event-properties:item=traceLevel}: User=${aspnet-user-identity}; ]
                                ${when:when=('${event-properties:item=traceLevel}' == 'Verbose' and 
            '${aspnet-request-method}' != 'GET')   > 0 and length('${mdlc:item=RequestId}') > 0:inner=${newline}Request-Body\: ${aspnet-request-posted-body}}
                                ${newline}Logger name: ${logger} 
                                ${newline}" />
```

1. `${aspnet-request-posted-body}` and `${mdlc:item=RequestId}` used in nlog file
2. To enable `${aspnet-request-posted-body}` in startup I used this code.

```cs
              app.Use(async (context, next) =>                     
              {
                            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
                            await next?.Invoke();
              });
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would probably start with something simple like this:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\Logs\Api_.log"
            layout="RequestId=${mdlc:item=RequestId} RequestBody=${aspnet-request-posted-body}" />
```

And then enable the NLog InternalLogger at Debug-Level and look for clues:

- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging
- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

You also need to correctly register NLog as LoggingProvider with the method `UseNLog()`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

If you are not using Microsoft `ILogger` for logging within the context for the active HttpRequest, then `RequestId` will not be available.

[NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.1](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/781) needs help from middleware for [${aspnet-request-posted-body}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-posted-body-layout-renderer) to work:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<NLog.Web.NLogRequestPostedBodyMiddleware>();
```